# No query result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this sql query that returns no result. The table it queries has data but no results being pull. The query is put into an array.

```
    $qry = array();
    $qry[] = "SELECT events_id as 'Reference ID', event_level as 'Level', events_date as 'Date', events_time as 'Time', events_opponent as 'Opponent', events_place as 'Place', events_results as 'Results'";

    $qry[] = "FROM wp_events WHERE events_id = ".$sched_id."";

    $val = array();
    $val =  implode(" ", $qry);
    $result = $wpdb->get_results($val, ARRAY_A);
```

i `var_dump` the `$result` but it only output `Array ( )`. I also tried to `var_dump($val)`  if there is something wrong on the query but query is ok. I don't know what im missing here. please help.

Comment: Run the query from the command line and see if you get an error

Comment: Ok john, i'll try that now.

Comment: It says there is an error in this line of code `$qry = array();` but that code is fine. I removed it and it says again that  `$qry[] = "SELECT events_id as 'Reference ID', event_level as 'Level', events_date as 'Date', events_time as 'Time', events_opponent as 'Opponent', events_place as 'Place', events_results as 'Results'";` having an error. but there no error on that query.

Comment: Maybe on the other hand there could be some alternative on how to setup my query. aside from the query i was doing. But i don't have any idea what is it.

Comment: The single quotes around the alias names look like errors to me.  Run the query outside of php to get a better feel for what is going on.

Comment: the query works with the single qoutes on it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two points in this code which can remain problematic:

- Do you always have the `$sched_id` filled?
- Does passing a complete query string to the `$wpdb->get_results()` return anything?

Try doing a fully complete query in phpMyAdmin to see the expected result and work the PHP code until you have the same results back.

Comment: Yes `$sched_id` always have data whenever the query runs. One thing also is that this query works before without the `WHERE clause` just plain `$qry[] = "SELECT events_id as 'Reference ID', event_level as 'Level', events_date as 'Date', events_time as 'Time', events_opponent as 'Opponent', events_place as 'Place', events_results as 'Results'";
$qry[] = "FROM wp_events";` Then when adding that `WHERE clause` query won't return my expected result. I tried this into phpMyadmin and it return the info i needed.

Comment: Could you give us an example of the $sched_id? Is it an integer?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this if u want to print variable values..

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['value'];//value received from array[]

$N = count($id);

for($i=0; $i <N; $i++)

{
    $result_h = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` where id='$id[$i]'");
    $pks_h = mysql_fetch_array($result_h);

echo $pks_h['mysql coloumn name'];
} 

?>
```

or use while loop if u want to print only mysql table value.